# go_router causing all screens in the Navigation stack to rebuild on each push-and pop operation

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-go-router

I'm using [go_router 10.0.0](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router) and it rebuilds every screen in the navigation stack every time I do push or pop.
All screens are StatlessWidget and declare it as const constructors as I'm saving the state of each screen using State Management (using BLOC)

This behavior causes unnecessary screen build, unnecessary API calls and makes the screen lose its state
How to solve This?
My code

```
  static GoRouter appRoutes = GoRouter(
    navigatorKey: _navKey,
    initialLocation: "/${_intialRout(_hiveManager, _configRoute)}",
    observers: AppConstant.navigatorObservers(),
    routerNeglect: true,
    routes: [
    
      ///SignInMethodsScreen
      GoRoute(
        name: Routes.signInMethods,
        path: "/${Routes.signInMethods}",
        builder: (context, state) => const SignInMethodsScreen(),
      ),

      ///EnterEmailScreen
      GoRoute(
        name: Routes.enterEmailScreen,
        path: "/${Routes.enterEmailScreen}",
        builder: (context, state) => const EnterEmailScreen(),
      ),

      ///SignInScreen
      GoRoute(
        name: Routes.signinScreen,
        path: "/${Routes.signinScreen}",
        builder: (context, state) => const SignInScreen(),
      ),

      ///OtpScreen
      GoRoute(
        name: Routes.otpScreen,
        path: "/${Routes.otpScreen}",
        builder: (context, state) => const OtpScreen(),
      ),

      ///CreatePasswordScreen
      GoRoute(
        name: Routes.createPasswordScreen,
        path: "/${Routes.createPasswordScreen}",
        builder: (context, state) => const CreatePasswordScreen(),
      ),

      ///MainScreen
      GoRoute(
        name: Routes.mainScreen,
        path: "/${Routes.mainScreen}",
        builder: (context, state) => const MainScreen(),
      ),

 
    ],
  );
```

Comment: Why are you using `navKey`?

Comment: @Tayan it's because of another functionality, btw the cause of the rebuild is using GeRouterState.of(context) inside the build method

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I switched to auto route => https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route